# Connection rejected based on ACL filtering, but the ACL is disabled?

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, datagrip

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Cloud database through DataGrip (with JetBrains's instructions) but I'm getting an error:

```
DBMS: Oracle (no ver.)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
[66000][12506] ORA-12506: TNS:listener rejected connection based on service ACL filtering.
```

However, clearly the ACL is disabled:

[image: screenshot of oracle cloud dashboard showing that the access control list is disabled]

What could possibly be causing this error and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have set up your data source connection properly:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/how-to-connect-to-oracle-with-oci.html#step_1_preparing_drivers_for_the_oci_connection

If this doesn't work, please file an issue on [our tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) and provide the idea log from Help - Show Log in Files